Did Windows change the login screen behavior to explicitly prevent typing in a password until the screen is fully initialized?
In older versions of Windows (at least Windows XP, maybe as late as Windows 7), I used to be able to wake up the computer from sleep (by moving the mouse or hitting a key on the keyboard) and then nearly immediately begin typing my password.  I would be able to type and submit the password before the screen finished turning on.
In more recent versions (Windows 10+ at least) it seems like it has changed where I need to wait for the screen to completely turn on before I can even start typing.  The screen being on obviously isn't a prerequisite for the computer to accept keyboard input (the keyboard is plugged directly into the computer, not via a USB hub in the screen), and the keyboard is wired so it's not likely some delay from it initializing itself.
Is this something that was explicitly changed, and if so, does anybody have some details about the reasons why?

Possibly related to the change which prevented pasting a password into that screen.

Are you able to wake up the computer by typing something on the keyboard (not via the mouse)?

@harrymc Yup, moving the mouse or hitting a key on the keyboard.

Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

The behavior seems to be the same.
